# Generic column access for scala matrix

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming

I have code that stores matrices of different types, e.g. `m1: Array[Array[Double]], m2: List[List[Int]]`.  As seen, these matrices are all stored as as a sequence of rows.  Any row is easy to retrieve but columns seem to me to require traversal of the matrix.  I'd like to write a very generic function that returns a column from a matrix of either of these types.  I've written this in many ways, the latest of which is:

/* Get a column of any matrix stored in rows */

```
private def column(M: Seq[Seq[Any]], n: Int, c: Seq[Any] = List(),
                     i: Int = 0): List[Any] = {
    if (i != M.size) column(M, n, c :+ M(i)(n), i+1) else c.toList
```

This compiles however it doesn't work: I get a type mismatch when I try to pass in an Array[Array[Double]].  I've tried to write this with some view bounds as well i.e.

```
private def column[T1 <% Seq[Any], T2 <% Seq[T1]] ...
```

But this wasn't fruitful either.  How come the first code segment I wrote doesn't work? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the return type, this is a really simple way to do it:

```
  def column[A, M[_]](matrix: M[M[A]], colIdx: Int)
    (implicit v1: M[M[A]] => Seq[M[A]], v2: M[A] => Seq[A]): Seq[A] =
    matrix.map(_(colIdx))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

def column[T, M[_]](xss: M[M[T]], c: Int)(
  implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, T, M[T]],
           mm2s: M[M[T]] => Seq[M[T]],
           m2s: M[T] => Seq[T]
): M[T] = {
  val bf = cbf()
  for (xs <- mm2s(xss)) { bf += m2s(xs).apply(c) }
  bf.result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you represent a Matrix as an underlying single-dimensional Array (the only kind of Array there is!) and separately represent its structure in terms of rows and columns.

This gives you more flexibility both in representation and access. E.g., you can provide both row-major and column-major organizations. Producing row iterators is just as easy as producing column iterators, regardless of whether it's a row-major or column-major organization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
private def column[T](
 M: Seq[Seq[T]], n: Int, c: Seq[T] = List(), i: Int = 0): List[T] =
   if (i != M.size) column(M, n, c :+ M(i)(n), i+1) else c.toList
```

Comment: No luck:  type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[Array[Double]]
[error]  required: Seq[Seq[Double]]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.